# I want to add the name of my mailbox at the top of my page but it shows and goes off

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I want to add the name of my mailbox at the top of my page but it shows for few seconds and goes off.

What I want is for e.g. INBOX to show at the top of the page, then all the inbox mails will be below the title.

The INBOX shows for nanoseconds and then my inbox mails load and overshadows it.

How can I resolve this?

```js
function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#content-view').style.display = 'none';

  //Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;

  // display details of mailbox
  let output = '';

  // using get request to retrieve details
  fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(emails => {
      emails.forEach(email => {
        //display subjecct, sender and timestamp of mail
        output += `<div class="mail" onclick="viewEmail(${email.id}, ${mailbox})">
                    <button class="btn pr-5" style="min-width: 120px; display: inline-block;">${email.sender}</button> 
                    <button class="btn">${email.subject}</button>
                    <button class="badge float-right">${email.timestamp}</button> 
                    <span class="list-group-item"></span> 
                  </div>`;
      })
      //add to html emails view
      let emailList = document.querySelector('#emails-view');
      emailList.innerHTML = output;
    });


}
```

```html
<div id="emails-view">
</div>
```

Comment: What do you expect, you're overwriting it when your fetch finishes. Why not put your name in a different div?

Comment: @LeeTaylor, thanks, this is my first time using JS. Lesson learnt, have a good day. No longer able to click on - onclick="viewEmail(${email.id}, ${mailbox}) - and transfer to the inbox content.

Comment: @lee-taylor can you post that as an answer so that Chucks can accept it and mark the question as answered?

Comment: @Chuks Added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mailbox name is being overwritten as soon as your `fetch` request is processed.

You have two options.

1. Append the response to the name in one div
2. Use a separate div for the name and another div for the response.

#2 is far more preferable.